# Optimize MYSQL Select query in large table

Tags: mysql

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vendorid` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `year` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

Table size: **over 7 million**. *All fields are **not unique**, except id.*

Simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE title='milk'
```

Takes over 45s-60s to complete.

Tried to put unique index on title and description but got 1170 error.

How could I optimize it? Would be very grateful for suggestions.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: The terms `large` and `millions`  in regards to database tables are mutually exclusive. :^)

Comment: @NumLock I'd argue that a table with 800 million rows would be considered "large"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you expect there to not be a lot of rows, or you only want to return a handful anyway, then a non-unique index on `title` is the way to go. As this column is a `TEXT` datatype, you will need to constrain the length in some way, I've chosen 100.

```
create index sample_idx01 on sample (title (100))
```

An index doesn't require uniqueness by default.

Answer (score 7):

An index on the `title` field *may* help like Andrew mentions, because yes you generally want to index on the predicates of your query. But one other problem that jumps out at me with your example query is the fact it's using `SELECT *`.

When you use `SELECT *`, you're using an anti-pattern that can affect query performance and result in sub-optimal query plans from being used. My guess (would need to see the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) is the query plan you're currently getting is a scan against the entire clustered index (entire table). And that *may* continue to be the case, even after adding a secondary index on `title`.

Instead you should either explicitly list out only the columns you actually need to `SELECT` for that given query and possibly add them to your secondary index key as well (after the `title` column in the definition). Or if this query is pretty commonly used and does need all the columns selected, you should make `title` part of the clustered (primary) index which will then automatically include all the fields of the table clustered on `title`.

But regardless, you should stop using `SELECT *` and always explicitly list out the columns you need (even if it's all of the columns of the table) to improve readability and maintainability of your queries too.

Comment: In fact `SELECT *` is sometimes (most times) more maintainable as there's one less place to update when adding or removing a column.

Comment: And what do you offer with the clustered index option? `title, id` would lose the quick lookup by id and `id, title` would be useless for title lookups. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have changed title field to VARCHAR(64). Ran 5 times each of these queries: SELECT *... and SELECT title. Results: * = ~6s, title=10s. In my case, it appears * is more performant.

Comment: @Džuris Debatable on maintainability, but the comments isn't the place to do that. In a long batch of queries (such as with multiple CTEs) it may be hard to trace the source of a column when `SELECT *` is used everywhere instead of listing out the columns. Feel free to create a chat if you want to further discuss, instead of using the comments. To your second point, OP never stated they have a use case for just `id` only predicates, so if they don't then yes that would make sense.

Comment: @TadasV. It sounds like you're actually seeing similar results, and maybe seeing the same query plans for both now. That's not granular of a test that you did. I'm not sure if you made other changes at this point, such as Andrew's suggestion, but my point is using `SELECT *` can result in a full index scan, even on the clustered index as opposed to your secondary index, which would then make your secondary index useless and minimize your chances for the most optimal plan. It doesn't always happen, but is realistically possible. You can use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to compare query plans for testing.

Comment: I don't think `SELECT *` would affect the query plan. But if all the columns you're selecting are in the index that's used for the `WHERE` clause, it means it doesn't need to access the table content, the results can be fetched entirely from the index, which is more efficient.

Comment: @Barmar If you use `SELECT *` and your secondary index doesn't include every column, what do you think happens when it tries to locate the data for those other columns that are not part of your secondary index? It surely will result in a different query plan than if you just list only the columns you need especially if only the columns you need are part of the secondary index.

Comment: @J.D. It gets them from the row that the index used by `WHERE` points to.

Comment: @Barmar Accidentally hit send, please see my updated comment. But yes because it needs to do an additional lookup to find those columns (that don't exist in the secondary index), it will likely result in a different query plan and potentially more work to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

```
FULLTEXT(title)

WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('milk' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Read about FULLTEXT; it is very good for searching for "word(s)", but has limitations on the minimum word length (default 3), etc.

Comment: In my case minimum len is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think of another alternative, partition your table by the "year" field and spread the load across several DataFiles spread across different drives.  That would cause the load to be split into multiple parts and should decrease execution time.

Answer (score 0):

> Table size: over 7 million.

This is not a large number of rows.

The first thing to do would be to investigate locks. So you can run the query in one terminal, and then in another terminal, do a [SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html) and see what you get. If many concurrent queries are waiting for a lock on the same table, that's a problem. If the table type is MyISAM, writes lock out reads, so one long query on a MyISAM table can lock out all other connections and make your webserver run out of processes, for example. In any case, if you value the data, it's a good idea to switch the table to InnoDB.

Assuming no locking issues, next thing to look at is the actual size of the table. You can use phpmyadmin or just [query it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database). I'm having suspicions about that "description" column. If it is small, okay. But if you put 10 kB of text in there on average, your 7M rows table is going to use 70GB, which means even if the number of rows is small, it's definitely not something you want to access without thinking carefully about indexing.

You can do:

```
SELECT avg(length(title)), avg(length(description)), 
max(length(title)), max(length(description)) from yourtable;
```

to get an idea of what's in there, too.

If, as I suspect, the description column uses a huge amount of space, then that will be a problem. If you want to search on the small columns only (title, vendorid, year) then you need to keep that data in cache so it's fast. However, if each row has a big description column, that will fill your cache way faster than you'd want. That also increases the amount of IO required to fetch rows and filter them, making your queries slow.

So the strategy depends on whether you will use full-text search on the description or not.

If you do, then MYSQL full text search most likely won't be up to the task. Use something like Sphinx or Xapian instead.

If you don't search on the description, then it is likely you can use a MySQL fulltext index on the title column. However, I don't think MySQL can do a covering fulltext index and include the year column in it, which means we're back to the previous issue: the fulltext index will optimize searches on title, but if any filtering is done by year, then it will have to hit the table and clog up the cache with the descriptions of all the rows you don't want.

So if you don't search on description, there is a simple fix: put the description column in a separate table, linked with a foreign key. This makes the (id,title,year,vendorid) table much smaller, and able to fit in cache, so it will be less of a problem if the fulltext index can't offer coverage of the year/vendorid columns.